# Android my background camera app lost signal when an other app use the camera

Tags: android, flutter, google-api, android-camera, google-vision

What a tricky question, you will probably want more information..

I'm currently building an app that use the camera in background. This is ethic, and the user has been warned, so don't worry.

> I'm using [CameraSource](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/CameraSource) from `com.google.android.gms.vision`.

So the user is free to launch other app and do anything he want to do. Even start other app which access the camera ! Here problems come..

> I'm using [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) as framework.

When user open an other app that use the camera, my app lost signal and Flutter trace only print :

```
E/Camera  ( 3154): Error 2
```

Nothing else.. No Exceptions, No traces, Nothing to know here it come from, why or how to handle it !

If you have any idea how to restart the camera untill it's available again, it could save me days.

Comment: Possibly related: [Android P will Prevent Idle Background Apps from Accessing the Camera](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-p-background-apps-camera/) Given that you are using a Google API Library (not open source), I'm not sure if that library handles backgrounding.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. But my camera works in background. At least, untill an other app in foreground access it. What I want is to detect when the foreground app generate an error to my app so that I can handle it. Because no exception is thrown for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `cameraController.dispose()` when your the app stops (goes to the background or other application opens in top of the app).

Here is the example from the official camera documentation on how they handle app lifecycle for the camera.

```dart
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    // App state changed before we got the chance to initialize.
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return;
    }
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      controller?.dispose();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      if (controller != null) {
        onNewCameraSelected(controller.description); // Here we reinitialize the cameraController
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the [link](https://pub.dev/packages/camera/versions/0.9.4+14) to camera documentation.

Comment: That doesn't help. The aim was to use the camera in the background (with the user's consent) even if another app is in the foreground. Nevermind, we flipped into another solution now. This is a 2yo problem.

Comment: Ok, good to hear that this is not a problem anymore, I have struggled with the flutter camera a lot ))